# Laravel caching view errors Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am making a beautiful web app and got an error when trying to cache a view using command:

```
$view = View::make('templates.view1', array(
                'a' => $a,
                'b' => $b
        ));

Cache::put($key, $view, 30);
```

It throws

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

to my face. I've tried with remember method but not succeed.

```
Cache::remember($key, 30, function($a, $b){
            return View::make('templates.view1', array(
                'a' => $a,
                'b' => $b
            ));
        });
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `render()` method:

```
$view = View::make('templates.view1', array(
                'a' => $a,
                'b' => $b
        ))->render();
```

to convert this view to string. Otherwise you use `Illuminate\View\View` object